# Dynamic content security policy with Ember / JavaScript

Tags: javascript, ember.js, content-security-policy

We have an Ember-based site which is divided into two conceptual sections which require their own content security policy. There is currently a single CSP applied to the `index.html`.

Is it possible for a `Content-Security-Policy` header sent in an API/server response *after* page load to be honoured by the browser? I have attempted to send this header in an API response, but it appears to not be honoured by Chrome.

Comment: It’s not possible to send *any* headers after page load, right? That’s not the way HTTP works… The headers need to be sent before the response body. Have you tried instead delivering the policy with the `<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="…">` element?

Comment: We can send response headers from requests made to the API after page load. These response headers can include cookies which affect state - so it's not *completely* unreasonable (only mostly unreasonable) to imagine that CSP could work similarly. The meta approach may work well, thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should not be possible due to CSP specification (Level 2, 15 December 2016):

> 3.5. Policy applicability
>
> This section is not normative.
>
> Policies are associated with an protected resource, and enforced or monitored for that resource. If a resource does not create a new execution context (for example, when including a script, image, or stylesheet into a document), then any policies delivered with that resource are discarded without effect. Its execution is subject to the policy or policies of the including context.

Source: https://www.w3.org/TR/CSP2/#which-policy-applies

Changing CSP provided as HTML meta Element should also not be possible:

> 3.3. HTML meta Element
>
> [...]
>
> Note: Modifications to the content attribute of a meta element after the element has been parsed will be ignored.

Source: https://www.w3.org/TR/CSP2/#delivery-html-meta-element

Comment: Well that's blown it. Thanks.